# How can I change a images margin that is inside of a div

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code

```
<head>
    <style>
        /* Spritesheet is 2000 x 400 and has 5 frames horizontally */

        .crop {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .crop img {
            width: 2000px;
            height: 400px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="crop">
        <img id="pic" src="spritesheet.png" />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And I want to change the images margin with the id `pic` to `-400px` with a function.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using this function:

```
function MoveImage() {
    // using jQuery
    $('.crop img#pic').css({ 'margin-top': -400 });
    // using javascript
    // document.getElementById('pic').style.marginTop = '-400px';
}

MoveImage();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0nr377ob/)

Answer (score -1):

#pic { margin: 20px; }

or whichever value you would like, you would target the image itself with the ID you gave it.
when targeting an item via it's ID you will use # and when you target an item via it's class you would use .

Comment: using javascript, not CSS